# How to reverse lookup the foreign key in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have 2 models

```
class Vendor(models.Model):
    vendor_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Food(models.Model):
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    food_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I want to search for the vendors based on the vendor_name as well as food_title.

Currently, I am able to get the vendors using this filter:

```
keyword = "vendor name or food title"    
vendors = Vendor.objects.filter(vendor_name__icontains=keyword)
```

The above filter will only work for vendor names. But, I want to get the vendors based on the food title as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with a [**`Q`** object <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q):

```
from django.db.models import Q

Vendor.objects.filter(
    Q(vendor_name__icontains=keyword) | Q(food__food_title__icontains=keyword)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

```py
vendors = Vendor.objects.filter(Q(vendor_name__icontains=keyword) | Q(food_title__icontains=keyword))
```

But better yet, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/